# Is the set of limit points of a set equal to the closure of the interior of the set?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So I am conjecturing that $$U^{lim} = \overline{U^{int}}$$
Is this correct? Can you provide a proof or a counter example? I would be glad if you give the explanation without too many topology, since I am not very familiar with the subject.
To avoid confusion, this is my limit point definition $$ x \text{ is a limit point of } U \iff \forall \epsilon >0 \exists u\in U (u\in B(\epsilon, x)-\{x\})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. In $\Bbb R$, take $U=\Bbb Q$. Then the set of limit points of $U$ is $\Bbb R$, but the interior of $U$ is the empty set, and therefore the closure of the interior is also empty.

Comment: Thank you. What about $\overline{(\overline{U})^{int}}$? Could that be the limit points set?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: @MetinBektaş The Cantor set is a counter-example. It is closed but has no interior.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Right. Thanks.

Comment: @Metin Bektaş: Relevant to the questions you are asking -- [Kuratowski's closure-complement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem) AND [regular open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_open_set) AND [regular closed set](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Regular_Closed_Set). These definitions are in the setting of topological spaces, but if you don't know about topological spaces, then in these definitions you can replace the space $X$ with $\mathbb R$ or ${\mathbb R}^n.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, these are very interesting.